# How to setup Semantic-UI with less

Tags: less, themes, semantic-ui

How to setup semantic Ui with less so I can start working with it?

Comment: http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you friendly using bower all you need run is the following command

```
bower install semantic
```

It will download semantic packakge into bower_components with the distribution and source package.

Read more about bower here http://bower.io/

And since the build tool used in it is gulp, http://gulpjs.com/

Comment: I have installed using gulp, my confusion is how to start building a new theme? Does the theme in semantic mean the same as in wordpress or drupal?

Comment: theming to semantic would be different than theming to wordpress / drupal, here no server side templating is involved and what you create is a set of UI components. Please read the theming guide by semantic ui http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html

Comment: Sorry for bothering too much. do I use the site.variables to edit and then how do include it in to my own theme. please I am confused with the structure and how it works?

Comment: Thanks I am able to solve my issue, by using npm install semantic-ui